# Django Order_BY custom function

Tags: django, sql-order-by, models

I have field in model `roll_numb`. The`roll_numb` has values as follows.

```
070-001
070-007
070-343
080-002
080-008
```

When i `order_by` `roll_numb` the sorting is as it is above.
I want to split the roll_numb by `-` and sort by the remainder. (i.e. 001, 002, 008)

### Code

```
class Meta:
        ordering = ['roll_numb']
```

Comment: You could have two fields instead of one. One field storing the first part of the values and the second field storing the last part of the values. This way you will still be able to painlessly use the Meta.ordering Then, introduce the hyphen during rendering.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think it is not possible to order a `queryset` by method of `model` in Django's ORM scope.

So in order to sort your `queryset` by your custom method, I recommend 2 ways:

**First**

```
qs = mymodel.objects.all()
qs = sorted(qs, key: lambda i: i.roll_numb().split('-')[1])
```

**Second**

Add another field to your model, so enable Django's ORM to sort by the desired value:

```
MyModel(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['roll_numb_splitted']

   roll_numb_splitted = models.Charfield(max_length=3)

   def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # this is a check to run once
        if not self.pk:
            self.roll_numb_splitted = self.roll_numb().split('-')[1]
        return super(MyModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: The first solution should be `key=`, not `key:`. Thanks!

Comment: very very great idea the second solution, thanks!

Comment: Please note that the first approach will return a `list` and not a `queryset`.

Answer (score 10):

Annotate your queryset with a custom field:

```
from django.db.models.functions import Substr

YourModel.objects.annotate(roll_split=Substr('roll_numb', 5)).order_by('roll_split')
```

If you want to *always* have your models ordered, just move that annotation to the model's manager:

```
class YourModelManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        qs = super(YourModelManager, self).get_queryset()
        return qs.annotate(roll_split=Substr('roll_numb', 5)).order_by('roll_split')

class YourModel(models.Model):
    objects = YourModelManager()
```

Comment: should I remove `ordering` in `class Meta`?

Comment: Yes, as far as the manager takes care of the ordering by itself. Also, depending on the database backend you are using, there might be a more convenient way for splitting the `roll_numb` field (like PostgreSQL's `split_part()`).